# Postfix AUTH failed for SMTP (ubuntu)

Tags: email

I'm using a webmin with virtualmin setup on a Ubuntu with Postfix and Dovecot for pop, I can recieve messages but not send them, it only works with local php driven mails, when I try to connect to the smtp server I get:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "***", port 25, isSSL false
220 *** ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "****", port: 25

EHLO localhost
250-****
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=PLAIN", arg "DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 

535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

Authentication Failed
```

this is my postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ***
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ***
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_security_level = none
```

I've been searching for over 7hours now and getting ready to shoot myself so any help is grealty appreciated :)

Comment: Please post your Java client code, it may help. Also the postfix server log might have some info.
Which AUTH mechanisms have you tried?

Comment: I used this one: http://pingability.com/smtptest.jsp
what do you mean with which AUTH mechanisms?

Comment: Use your own code so you can tinker with it, then you can try each AUTH mechanism, ie: I would try PLAIN first. You should probably understand AUTH mechanisms first though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't configure Postfix to use Dovecot as authentication type. Do it. See the documentation for more information. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_type

Additional follow the [Dovecot Wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication) and [Postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html).